# Delphi 10.3 Debug: Can not open socket: Permission denied

Tags: android, delphi, debugging, delphi-10.3-rio

I'm trying to run a debug `hello world`app, but I only get the following error: "**Can not open socket: Permission denied**". I didn't change any of the default permissions of the "new project".  When running a Delphi sample "AccessCameraApp" app, under `Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\Samples\Object Pascal\Mobile Snippets\AccessCameraApp`, the same error occurs.
I'm using a MotoG6 mobile device with Android 8.0.0, Delphi 10.3 on Windows 10.

**SIMULATE ERROR**: By pressing F9 to run the application, the program is compiled correctly and installed on the device, however Debug is interrupted and the debugging of Delphi simply stops when app starts. But the app still runs on the device.

I have already read the Embarcadero pages related to the subject, but I could not solve it:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Android_Permission_Model
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Uses_Permissions
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Running_Your_Android_Application_on_an_Android_Device#Running_Your_Application_with_Clean_Data_and_Cache_Folders

Comment: There's an issue with Android 8.0 that prevents the Delphi debugger (and potentially debuggers in other dev tools) from working. You need to update to 8.1, or use another device that has it.

Comment: Thank you for the informations. I'll test your suggestions as soon as possible and report the result.

Comment: The device is visible with adb, or with Chrome at chrome://inspect/#devices ?

Comment: Yes, it's visible for both.

Comment: @DaveNottage, I've changed the device and I'm using another one with Android 9. The initial problem has disappeared, but Debug still doesn't work. After compiling the program (app opens properly on the device), the "Run" screen shows no errors neither warnings. Pressing the OK button on this screen displays the `Unable to start gdbserver on port '64311'. Port is already in use`. I changed the debug port in the menu "Run -> Parameters ...", field `Parameters = -debugport = 10020` (I changed it to several other ports too) but the problem persists and debud does not work.

Comment: Try restarting the device

Comment: Firewall is turned off?

Comment: Try using -autolaunch in your debug parameters.

Comment: I appreciate the attention of all, but I believe Delphi has no solution to this problem. After trying everything unsuccessfully, I switched the device back to another Motorola with Android 8.1 (I first tested on Motorola with Android 8.0, then on Huawei Android 9.0 and now in the third device). Debug works only now and there was no need to change or include any parameters in Delphi.

Comment: @wBB were you able to find solutions for this? or workaround perhaps?

Comment: No. Unfortunately, I haven't looked for solutions to this problem anymore.